# jQuery Dynamically create div, populate tbody and append to existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a `<div class='preferences-grid'>` which already exists.

On click of button `preferences-grid-btn-ok` I want to call the function `create()` which will:

1. create a new `<div class='preferences-container'>` and
2. populate the `tbody` based on a `for`.

My problem is that I can't `append` the rows created by the `for` to the `tbody` of the individual `<div class='preferences-container'>` that are being created each time the button is clicked.

When I'm using this:

```
jQuery(contents).find(".preferences-table-body").append(row);
```

no rows are appended and when I'm using

```
jQuery(".preferences-table-body").append(row);
```

the first time no rows are appended and after that the new rows are appended to all of the existing `<div class='preferences-container'>`

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/869/) link

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/n7cyE/871/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were creating a string `contents`, but jquery had no way of knowing of its existence.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c524Loam/

```
function create() {
    var contents = "..."

    var $contents = $(contents);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar').text('result ' + i);
        $contents.find(".preferences-table-body").append(row);
    }
    return $contents;
}
```

I created a new jquery object using `contents` and then manipulated it in the `for` loop. After return it gets appended to the markup.

Comment: I knew it was something that ridiculously simple! Sorry for bothering you and thanks for the quick response.